# WCF Service Log - create a new file when exceed a file size limit or create it for every day

Tags: wcf

My application is using WCF, And I am creating a service log file on server. It is working correctly, It is writing same svclog file and it is increasing in size.

What would I have to do to create a new svclog file when it reaches a fixed file size like I want it to be 50MB, or it creates a new svclog file for each day.

Currently, The source and listeners have been defined in the web.config file as follows:

```
<system.diagnostics>
<sources>
  <source name="System.ServiceModel.MessageLogging" switchValue="Warning, ActivityTracing">
    <listeners>
      <add name="ServiceModelTraceListener" />
    </listeners>
  </source>
  <source name="System.ServiceModel" switchValue="Verbose,ActivityTracing">
    <listeners>
      <add name="ServiceModelTraceListener" />
    </listeners>
  </source>
  <source name="System.Runtime.Serialization" switchValue="Verbose,ActivityTracing">
    <listeners>
      <add name="ServiceModelTraceListener" />
    </listeners>
  </source>
</sources>
<sharedListeners>
  <add initializeData="C:\ServiceLogs\app_tracelog.svclog" type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" name="ServiceModelTraceListener" traceOutputOptions="Timestamp" />
</sharedListeners>
</system.diagnostics>
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should create a custom trace listener.
There is a perfect sample from MS for this ! This example can not fit exactly with your needs, but it is easy to understand and so to change.

More info [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa395205.aspx)